# How to tell alltt not to skip lines at beginning/end?

Tags: line-breaking, verbatim, knitr

It seems like there is no option for specifying that, like a hack for `verbatim` I found on tex.stackexchange:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\makeatletter
\preto{\@verbatim}{\topsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt}
\makeatother
```

`\begin{alltt}` skips a line before en after its content, how can I remove this ? I tried to use the code below with `@alltt` instead of `@verbatim` but it doesn't work.

Indeed I am using `knitr` which places code input in `alltt` environment, there may be some other `knitr` specific solutions too I might be interested in.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%

\begin{document}

Few words
\begin{alltt}
alltt words
\end{alltt}
something else

\begin{verbatim}
verbatim words
\end{verbatim}
and with the hack:

\makeatletter
\preto{\@verbatim}{\topsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{verbatim}
verbatim words
\end{verbatim}
the end

\end{document}
```

[image: alltt and verbatim]

Comment: Does `knitr` not use `\begin{document}` `\end{document}`? If it does, please provide the rest of your MWE Perhaps upload an image of output?

Comment: `knitr` automatically produces a .tex file form the `.Rnw`; it's not directly related to my question but I thought there might be `knitr` options to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `\@alltt` but like `verbatim` (and most latex display constructs) `alltt` is a trivlist so the same settings apply, you just need

```
\preto{\alltt}{\topsep=0pt \partopsep=0pt}
```

Comment: ok, not an expert of tex elements, but works like a charm, thanks! (trivlist, didn't even know what it is!). Is there a way to remove only the first line break and to keep the final one ?